# How to fix MongoError: no geo indices for geoNear

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a collection with a Geometry type. Now I would like, for a given point, get the nearest document. I am trying to use $geoNear operator with MongoDb. But in my callback I catch an error "MongoError: no geo indices for geoNear". I suppose than I have to define an index to my collection.

So I tried to launch this command :
$ db..createIndex({locationCoordinate:"2dsphere"});

But that doesn't change nothing.

This is my schema definition:

```
const MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  logo: { type: String, required: true },
  locationCoordinate: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point'],
      default: 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true,
      unique: true
    }
  },
  name: { type: String, required: true }
}, {
  writeConcern: 'majority',
});
```

And this is my aggregate function:

```
myModel.aggregate([
 {
   $geoNear: {
      near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 17 , 65 ] },
      distanceField: "distance",
      spherical: true
   }
 }
  ], (err, results) => {
    console.log("Err", err)
  })
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the index like this:

```
function waitForIndex() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        YourModel.on('index', error => error ? reject(error) : resolve());
    });
}
```

And then perform the async operations.

Comment: Thanks. I add waitForIndex function and I execute myModel.agregate when waitForIndex is finished but I still have the same error.

Comment: you should use it before doing the aggregation. i.e `myModel.save().then(waitForIndex).then(aggregate).catch(err=> ...)` @popidep